# FastAPI.Path : TypeError: Path() missing 1 required positional argument: 'default'

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

From tutorials I've seen the below used. However, when I try to replicate (running Docker container locally) I observe the below error.

```
@app.get("/get-student/{student_id}") # path parameters and query parameters have no overlap
def get_student(student_id: int = Path(
        description="student ID", 
        gt=0 #minimum ID = 1,        
        )
    ):
    return students[student_id]
```

Error:

```
  File "/code/app/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    def get_student(student_id: int = Path(
TypeError: Path() missing 1 required positional argument: 'default'
```

When I review [official documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params-numeric-validations/#import-path), default is not passed in as an argument. Nor do I see any data on how it should be used.

This leads me to two questions:

1. Why is default required in my use case?
2. Is using a Path best practice / what problem does it solve?

Edit: Documentation claims that adding * as the first arg will resolve. However, I have not observed this to be the case.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Path

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_items(*, item_id: int = Path(title="The ID of the item to get"), q: str):
    results = {"item_id": item_id}
    if q:
        results.update({"q": q})
    return results
```

Additionally Docs also call for using Annotated, however, I'm still observing the same error:

```
@app.get("/get-student/{student_id}") # path parameters and query parameters have no overlap
def get_student(student_id = Annotated[int, Path(
        description="student ID", 
        gt=0 #minimum ID = 1,        
        )]):
    return students[student_id]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing documentation for the latest version of FastAPI but up until 0.78.0 you needed to specify a value for `default` (usually `...`) when specifying other optional arguments.

From the [release notes](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/releases/tag/0.78.0):

> ✨ Add support for omitting ... as default value when declaring required parameters with:
>
> Path()
>
> ...
>
> Up to now, declaring a required parameter while adding additional validation or metadata needed using ... (Ellipsis).